# JavaScript onSubmit form handling

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I'm trying to make a Chrome extension that takes in user input in the form of a query, scrapes Flickr's API for images related to that query (effectively searching it for the query), and then places them, as well as links to their locations, onto the page. I stole it from a tutorial site, whose example extension did the above without the user input and the links. I tried to do the links myself, which I failed miserably at, and so had to get help here. Now, I'm failing miserably at setting up the user input. I first tried PHP, which crashed my chrome since it apparently doesn't work in extensions, so now I'm trying to go JS all the way. I tried doing an onsubmit event for my search form, and then I realised I have to have **all my code** in the `{}` of my onsubmit function. Unfortunately, due to the way variables are declared in JavaScript, it doesn't work since if everything is inside a function, then all the variables declared are rendered *private*. Therefore, other functions inside the main one are unable to use them, rendering the script useless. The ideal solution to that would be a way to declare public variables inside a function, unfortunately after searching for half an hour I couldn't find any ways that work/I understand. Can someone please help me? I'll be perfectly happy with any other method, as I will be if you tell me that all my prognosis is wrong and why - I'm quite a noob at this.

My code so far:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open(
"GET",
"http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?" +
    "method=flickr.photos.search&" +
    "api_key=90485e931f687a9b9c2a66bf58a3861a&" +
    "text=cake&" +
    "safe_search=1&" +  
    "content_type=1&" +  
    "sort=relevance&" +  
    "per_page=24",
true);
req.onload = showPhotos;
req.send(null);


function showPhotos() {
  var photos = req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("photo");

  for (var i = 0, photo; photo = photos[i]; i++) {
    var photos = req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("photo");
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute("href",constructImageURL(photo));
    a.setAttribute("target","_blank");

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("src",constructImageURL(photo));

    a.appendChild(img);
    document.getElementById("images").appendChild(a);
  }
}

function constructImageURL(photo) {
  return "http://farm" + photo.getAttribute("farm") +
  ".static.flickr.com/" + photo.getAttribute("server") +
  "/" + photo.getAttribute("id") +
  "_" + photo.getAttribute("secret") +
  "_s.jpg";
}
```

This is without my failed onsubmit code. The HTML page itself only consists of a tag importing the above script, a div for the images and a form:

```
<div id="images">
</div>
<form name="queryForm" onsubmit="javascript: querySubmit()">
Search: <input type='text' name='query'>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why I hate jQuery.. see my HTML 5 form examples ...

http://netjs.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/91818#1775033

http://netjs.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/91818#1775035

You need to add an event to the form e.g.

`myform.addEvent('submit', myFunction);`

Then from there handle what you need to do...

Granted jQuery has little to to with this and its more likley because you don;t understand javascript which jQuery facilitates because it turns everything into DOM like shit.
You are just using bad practices and you need to de-couple your logic into various functions for maintain-ability.